# Vertical centering with flex box not working even with most basic code

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm sure this is a duplicate question but I've eliminated almost everything from my code and still can't get it to work.  I am new to Flexbox and tried to follow the code at https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/ (as an aside, even *that* code doesn't work!).  I am using Safari 11.1.1 and Chrome 67.0.3396.87 so it's not that they're old browsers.

I'm trying to center a `<div>` horizontally and vertically on the screen.  The div contains a form which contains a couple of inputs and a button.  I'm trying to center each of this horizontally and the group should be entered vertically within the `<div>`.

In Safari,nothing is centred.  In Chrome, the div is centred horizontally but not vertically, but the inputs/button are not centred either horizontally and vertically.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="something">
      <input type="text" placeholder="something else">
      <button>An Action</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

What am I missing?  As said, even the sample code from the site mentioned above didn't work correctly, so I'm quite stumped.

Comment: if it is supposed to be centered on the viewport, then body requires an height at least equal at viwport's height .. 100vh ?

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: The `body` will collapse to the height of the content unless explicity set to 100% or 100vh

Comment: it seems to be in center in result

Comment: could you please better explain what you want

Comment: i think you should use <br> tag

Comment: if you do not give an height to body, then the #holder  is the only thing sizing body, and centering is active but unseen. Give an height to your container.(body) If justify-content and align-items are confusing you , you can also use margins and even combined them. an example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJLZBL (note, that many containers might not even be needed, the form on its own can do the job https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKVzwR )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `height:100vh` in `body`, or set `height:100%` on `html,body`

And center items in forms, use flexbox properties in `form` instead of `#holder`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form>* {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="something">
    <input type="text" placeholder="something else">
    <button>An Action</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  When I set the height of body it didn't work.  Only when I also set -- as you did -- the margin to 0 did it work.  Why does Flexbox seem to be dependent on the margin?

Comment: And thanks for pointing out (everyone) that I can use form as a flex container.  I was mixing it up with fieldset, which can't be as far as I know.

Comment: @Cerulean the `margin:0`it iis only to reset the default `margin:8px` in `body` which `100vh` would sum up and therefore appear the vertical scrollbar